# How to get interval days in python DataFrame and write calculation formula

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It has a start date and an end date. In the dataframe below, I want to extract data where the date of the "UPDATE DATE" item is between the start date and the end date or the "STUDY" item is unique.

```
   STUDY              Teacher       UPDATE_DATE
0   math            None -> A    2021-05-12
1   math            A -> A, B    2021-09-23
2   math            A, B -> A    2021-10-12 
3   math            A -> A, C    2022-02-25
4   science         None -> A    2021-07-01
5   science         A -> D       2021-09-09
6   science         D -> D, B    2022-01-03
7   entertainment   None -> C    2022-01-01
8   entertainment   C -> B, C    2022-03-02
9   technology      None -> E    2021-09-01

from_date = '2022-01-01'
to_date = '2022-04-10'
df['UPDATE_DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['UPDATE_DATE'])
t = df['STUDY'].value_counts()
us = t[t==1].index.values
df = df.loc[(df['UPDATE_DATE'] >= from_date) & (df['UPDATE_DATE'] <= to_date)|(df['STUDY'].isin(us))]

output:

   STUDY              Teacher       UPDATE_DATE
3   math            A -> A, C    2022-02-25
6   science         D -> D, B    2022-01-03
7   entertainment   None -> C    2022-01-01
8   entertainment   C -> B, C    2022-03-02
9   technology      None -> E    2021-09-01
```

Next, Q.I want to split the value of the "Teacher" field based on the arrow and copy the row, I want to create an "INTERVAL_DAYS" field and add calculated values ​​using the "UPDATE_DATE" item.

(ADD) -> Whenever the teacher of the study is changed, it is recorded in this dataframe. The final thing I want to find is the number of studies each Teacher is in charge of. One study is viewed as "1". So, taking math STUDY as an example, split the teacher based on the arrow, the number of teachers “A” from 2022-01-01 (start date) to 2022-02-25, 2022-02-25 to 2022- Until 04-10 (end date), I'm trying to obtain the counts in charge of teachers A and C.
(* 2022-01-01 ~ 2022-04-10: 99(days))

```
   STUDY              Teacher       UPDATE_DATE    INTERVAL_DAYS
   math                     A        2022-02-25            0.55 (* 55/99, '55' is the period from 2022-01-01 to 2022-02-25)
   math                  A, C        2022-02-25            0.44 (* 45/99)
   science                  D        2022-01-03            0.02 (* 2/99) 
   science               D, B        2022-01-03            0.98 (* 97/99) 
   entertainment            C        2022-01-01            0.6 (* 60/99)
   entertainment         B, C        2022-03-02            0.4 (* 39/99)
   technology               E        2021-09-01              1
```

The blueprint is drawn in my head, but I am having a hard time writing code in python. It seemed like it would be a simpler solution than I thought, but I haven't been able to solve this problem for a long time. Please help.

Comment: I think there is some problem with your second question example. Please check it.

Comment: keramat
Thanks for solving the problem. And I checked and corrected the explanation that was omitted in the second question. Please confirm. thank you.

Comment: Actually, it is not clear to me yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
t = df['STUDY'].value_counts()
us = t[t==1].index.values
df.loc[(df['UPDATE_DATE'] >= from_date) & (df['UPDATE_DATE'] <= to_date)|(df['STUDY'].isin(us))]
```

Demonstration:

```
string = """ind    STUDY    Teacher    UPDATE_DATE
0    math    None -> A    2021-05-12
1    math    A -> A, B    2021-09-23
2    math    A, B -> A    2021-10-12 
3    math    A -> A, C    2022-02-25
4    science    None -> A    2021-07-01
5    science    A -> D       2021-09-09
6    science    D -> D, B    2022-01-03
7    entertainment    None -> C    2022-01-01
8    entertainment    C -> B, C    2022-03-02
9    technology    None -> E    2021-09-01"""
data = [x.split('    ') for x in string.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])


#solution
from_date = '2022-01-01'
to_date = '2022-04-10'
df['UPDATE_DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['UPDATE_DATE'])
t = df['STUDY'].value_counts()
us = t[t==1].index.values
df = df.loc[(df['UPDATE_DATE'] >= from_date) & (df['UPDATE_DATE'] <= to_date)|(df['STUDY'].isin(us))]
```

Output:

[image]